# Docker-compose file builds same images twice

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build images for my app. However, when I run "docker-compose up" command, it builds some of the containers twice. I couldn't figure the reason of it. I think the tags cause this kind of situation, but I couldn't figure where 'latest' tag come from.

Here it is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks.
      # see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - elk
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
    networks:
      - elk
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: 'yes'
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: CLIENT
    links:
      - logstash

  app:
    container_name: "ml-pipeline"
    build: .
    ports:
    - "7000:7000"
    - "5001:5001"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - elasticsearch
      - logstash
    networks:
      - elk
    links:
      - kafka

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

And output of this is:

[image]

As you can see there are duplicate images. How can I solve it ?

Comment: where are the duplicated images ? all your images are unique

Comment: @LinPy docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana and twitter-stream-dl-docker_kibana are the sama images, even if their size are the same. They are just increasing size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3 ELK containers have a build context with a Dockerfile that *by default* only consists of a FROM line. In the Dockerfiles you could add additional plugins.

#### part of your docker-compose.yml:

```
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
```

#### logstash/Dockerfile:

```
ARG ELK_VERSION

# https://github.com/elastic/logstash-docker
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${ELK_VERSION}

# Add your logstash plugins setup here
# Example: RUN logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-json
```

docker-compose pulls the Image `docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${ELK_VERSION}` and builds it's own version version `twitter-stream-dl-docker_XXX`. Since the build doesn't do anything it simply tags the old image with the new tag so they have the same Image ID.

In case you're wondering your folder's name is `twitter-stream-dl-docker` so the images have that tag (or you used `docker-compose -p twitter-stream-dl-docker`).

I hope that clears things up, but feel free to ask anything that's ambigious.

Comment: Will I see only 1 Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana image when I use this `docker-compose -p twitter-stream-dl-docker`, right ?

Comment: This is actually the correct answer! The `FROM` commands in the `Dockerfile`s will download the `docker.elastic.co/...` images as base images. But since there are no other commands in the `Dockerfile`s the resulting final images are identical with the downloaded base images.
If you don't add anything else to the images use [`image`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image) instead of [`build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) in the `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: With [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) or the [`--profile-name` / `-p` flag](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) you can set the project name which will affect the image names but they will be built regardless.

Comment: I used `docker-compose -p twitter-stream-dl-docker up` command. It didn't work. Later on, I will try to use `image` instead of `build` in `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: The `-p` flag is only responsible for the project's name which means a prefix for images, volumes, containers, networks. By default the project's name is the folder's name, but you can overwrite it with an ENV Variable or the `-p` flag. As acran pointed out it, you want to use the `image` directly without the build context in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Using `image` instead of `build` worked. However, I couldn't say same thing for `-p`. Image names are not `twitter-stream-dl-docker_XXX`. It is like `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch`. It is not very important, but is there any way to edit that ?

Comment: The project name affects <build> images not <all> images. In your question you had a build context and subsequently build the images yourself. After you removed the the build context and used the image directly there was no need to build the images again so there was no need for a new tag. Therefore you see the old image names. The `-p` flag still affects the container, network and volume names. They will all start with whatever you type after it e.g. `docker-compose -p XXX` -> container names start with XXX

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is nothing that indicates that `docker-compose` built the images twice. Your screenshot shows that the images have multiple tag names. But without further context it's hard to say how this happened and how `docker-compose` was involved in this.

One possible cause for this:

- the pre-built images from `docker.elastic.co` were downloaded by `docker pull docker.elastic.co/...` or another `docker run` command
- `docker-compose up` was looking for images named `twitter-stream-dl-docker_*` and since it couldn't find them triggered a `docker-compose build`
- `docker-compose build` built the images - but using the `docker` build cache it could re-use all layers of the existing `docker.elastic.co/...` images which must have been built from the same source
- the new built images resulted in the same final images which were then tagged with the name expected by `docker-compose`, i.e. `twitter-stream-dl-docker_*`

If you want to force a new local built either:

- build without using the cache: `docker-compose build --no-cache`
- delete the downloaded images: `docker rmi docker.elastic.co/...`

Comment: Thank you for gentle and detailed answer. I influenced from this repository by writing my own docker-compose.yml. Can you check this out ? https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk Can you tell me the changes that need to be done to fix this ?

Comment: Also I cannot delete the downloaded images `docker.elastic.co/...` Because it referenced with other images.

Comment: Depends strongly on what you want to _fix_ here because there is actually nothing broken? To delete/untag the downloaded images first delete all containers using them. To build your own images try using `--no-cache`. But right now the builds result in the exact same images since they are built with the exact same commands and files. So the result is the expected/correct one.